# Fetching MySQL data going through multiple tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I'm wanting to do the following:

Select everything from `product` that matches the value of `type_id` from both tables `product` and `system_type`. Then with *those* matched results, match `cat_id` from both tables `system_type` and `system_cat` and then refine the final result where `cat_type = 0` from the `system_cat` table.

Current SQL seems to have a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM product
JOIN system_type
    USING (type_id)
JOIN system_cat
    USING (cat_id)
WHERE cat_type = 0
```

What else I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM product
JOIN system_type
    USING system_type.type_id = product.type_id
JOIN system_cat
    USING system_type.cat_id = system_cat.cat_id
WHERE system_cat.cat_type = 0
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server here? (Two different products.)

Comment: @jarlh MySQL, I'm running it all through PhpMyAdmin

Comment: USING (type_id)..., or ON system_type.type_id = product.type_id

Comment: @jarlh I can't believe I forgot the parentheses, although still get the error.

Comment: Avoid `USING`, because you may end up connecting tables you didn't intend (since it doesn't actually know which table you want).  Use `... JOIN system_type ON system_type.type_id = product.type_id ...` instead.

Comment: And what's the error message? (Query 1 is perfectly fine syntax-wise.)

Comment: @jarlh You've fixed it with the second query using `ON` and not `USING` also thanks @Clockwork-Muse

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You may need to explicitely type out the columns you need

```
SELECT * FROM product as pr 
INNER JOIN system_type as st
    ON st.type_id = pr_id
INNER JOIN system_cat as sc
    ONH st.cat_id = sc.cat_id
WHERE sc.cat_type = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax changes when using `table_name.column` method. Use `ON` and not `USING`.

```
SELECT * FROM product
JOIN system_type
    ON system_type.type_id = product.type_id
JOIN system_cat
    ON system_type.cat_id = system_cat.cat_id
WHERE system_cat.cat_type = 0
```